# Too many re renders on react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm getting this too many re-renders error when I'm running this, this is in react. I ve already searched on many forums but still no luck. I know why this is happening because I ve used setState in useEffect, and is looping.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getClassData();
  }, []);

  //setClassData(stateData);
  const getClassData = ()=> {
    axios.post(`${apiEndPoint}/get/class/student`, ApiData, {
      headers: headers
    }).then(response => {
      const classArray = response.data;
      stateData=classArray;
      setClassData(classArray);
    })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }
  console.log(stateData);
  return(
    <ClassListGenerator classArrayData={classData}/>
  )
};
```

Comment: can you reproduce it in CodeSandbox ?

Comment: it is proprietry code so I cant, but I this this code is enough, other elelemts doesnt matter

Comment: I see that the wrong code `setClassData(stateData)` has beed commented, is there any problem?

Comment: I tried something there, it didnt work

Answer (score -1):

Why do you directly mutate state?
Try this in your `then` block

```
  const classArray = response.data;
  setClassData(classArray);
```